# How to add labels in a contour plot using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, contour

I'm doing a contour plot with `ggplot2` and I'm trying to add the labels like [this tutorial](https://eliocamp.github.io/metR/reference/geom_text_contour.html). However, always appears the following error:

`Error in geom_text_contour(aes(z = z)) : could not find function "geom_text_contour"`

```
library(ggplot2)

x <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
y <- c(0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2)
z <- seq(0,11,1)

df <- data.frame(x,y,z)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, z = z)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = z)) +
  geom_contour(colour = "white") +
  geom_text_contour(aes(z = z))
```

[image]

Comment: `devtools::install_github("eliocamp/metR"); library(metR)`

Comment: @markus It didn't work

Comment: downvote for "it didn't work". You should provide full code and complete error messages rather than a useless statement that tells us nothing about what was done or what response were obtained.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel, just needed to install and load the `metR` package.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(metR)
v <- data.table::melt(volcano)
g <- ggplot(v, aes(Var1, Var2)) +
  ggplot2::geom_contour(aes(z = value))
g + metR::geom_text_contour(aes(z = value)) + ggplot2::ggtitle("03/05/19 - Daniel")
```

[image]