# How to plot chart by ggplot2 with fixed scale?

Tags: r, ggplot2, mapping, surface

I need to draw different kind of pics using ggplot2 in R and it have to be in proper scale when I print it. It means that I have to define exact image and chart size, the same scale of x/y-axes.

Could you please advice me what kind of options I should to use?

```
ggplot(Surface, aes(x, y, z = z)) +
  geom_contour_filled(binwidth = 10, alpha = 0.6) +
  geom_textcontour(binwidth = 20, size = 2.5)
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what exactly you mean with fixed x/y scale (you might want to look into `coord_fixed`). Defining the plot size is not a simple problem, but it largely depends on your so called device size. (that is, the bit in which your plot is drawn, which you could see for example as a window or as a file with a specific size). Some parts of your plot are fixed in size (mostly the fonts), and many are resized depending on the device size. As you are talking about printing/saving, you will also want to look into `ggsave`

Comment: I try to explain. I need to plot map of surface and I know that x changes from 0 to 100 km, y from 0 to 200 km. So chart have to have exact 1:2 ratio and I need to print it to A4, so I know the image size with 300 dpi. Also all labels should be between chart and image border and I want to control margin size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to use `coord_fixed` with `ratio` argument:

> aspect ratio, expressed as y / x

Here is your code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(Surface, aes(x, y, z = z)) +
  geom_contour_filled(binwidth = 10, alpha = 0.6) +
  geom_textcontour(binwidth = 20, size = 2.5) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 2/1)
```

Comment: I tried and think it doesn't work ( I use xlim & ylim and also ratio, and expect that (ymax - ymin) / (xmax - xmin) the same values if I measure axes values and image in pixels.
[example](https://imgur.com/a/loxOar7)

`ggplot(df, aes(x, y, z = z)) + geom_contour_filled(bins = 5, alpha = 0.7) + xlim(140000, 152000) + ylim(7494000, 7520000) +theme(legend.position = "none") + coord_fixed(ratio = 12/26)`

Comment: Hi @Aleksandr, Could you please try `ratio=26/12`?

Comment: Hi! Yes, it looks worse https://i.imgur.com/DEeUmfF.png

Comment: I've got it. With xlim&ylim I need to use ratio(1/1). It works, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean `geom_text_contour` from `metR` package then we could do:

This example is taken from here [How to add labels in a contour plot using ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55975973/how-to-add-labels-in-a-contour-plot-using-ggplot2) (credits @bbiasi)

```
library(metR)
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

v <- data.table::melt(volcano)
ggplot(v, aes(Var1, Var2)) +
  ggplot2::geom_contour(aes(z = value))+
  metR::geom_text_contour(aes(z = value)) 

# adding ggsave with width and height
ggsave("test_myplot.png", width = 9, height = 7)
```

[image]